# How to use gdk_device_get_position()?

Tags: c, gtk, glib, mouse-cursor, gdk

I am trying to get the pointer position on screen in Gdk and found `gdk_display_get_pointer()`, which works fine, but it's marked as deprecated and refers to `gdk_device_get_position()` now.

But how do I use this function? I cannot get a `GdkDevice`, since there is no factory, nor is there a constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use Gdk.DeviceManager.

```
.....
.....
GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ();
GdkDeviceManager *device_manager = gdk_display_get_device_manager (display);
GdkDevice *device = gdk_device_manager_get_client_pointer (device_manager);

// do whatever with Gdk.Device, i.e:
int x, y;
gdk_device_get_position (device, NULL, &x, &y);
printf ("x= %d, y=%d", x,y);
```

Comment: Thought I might add for anyone interested in getting the cursor position in the window, you can use `gdk_window_get_device_position (gtk_widget_get_window(gtk_window), device, &x, &y, NULL);
`

Comment: Should I worry about the speed of calling these three functions? In the end I need to call `gdk_window_get_device_position`, as jackw11111 remarked, but I only have a GtkDrawingArea (widget). It seems a bit strange to be forced to call `gdk_window_get_device_position(gtk_widget_get_window(my_widget), gdk_device_manager_get_client_pointer(gdk_display_get_device_manager(gdk_display_get_default()), &x, &y, NULL);` just to get the x and y in my drawing area :/

Answer (score 6):

Since GTK+ 3.20+, luciomrx's answer becomes:

```
GdkDisplay* display = gdk_display_get_default();
GdkSeat* seat = gdk_display_get_default_seat(display);
GdkDevice* pointer = gdk_seat_get_pointer(seat);
```